# CSS Visual Studio 2015 Float positioning

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, css-float

On the PC I used at my uni the positioning of my DIVs was working correctly both in DESIGN view of the Visual Studio 2015 Community and in Internet Explorer/Chrome browser debug mode. It was looking like this:

[image: 9 divs, 3 columns and 3 rows]

At home I'm using the same version of Visual Studio as I did at the Uni.

The idea is that there are supposed to be 3 rows, and each row has 3 divs. The middle divs should be wider than the ones on the left and right, and left_mid/right_mid top_mid/bot_mid DIVs should have borders.

I put `float:left` on left divs(left_top, left_mid, left_bot), `float:right` on divs that I want to position on the right(right_top, right_mid, right_bot) and `width:auto` on the middle divs(mid_top, mid_mid, mid_bot).

It's simple thinking and it was working just fine. When I opened the solution at home the DIVs are looking as they are supposed to in DESIGN view - however in browser view when I debugged with IE/Chrome - they didn't have any height for some reason. After some time I figured out that for some reason I had to put height and width on FORM and then those little guys got back their height.
Why? I don't know, didn't need to set height and width on the FORM before.

However, that doesn't solve the problem. Their positioning is incorrect - the left_top DIV is where it is supposed to be - in left top corner of the page. Right_top DIV is also positioned correctly, it's in the right top corner of my page. HOWEVER, for some unknown reason the middle DIV(mid_top) is being positioned at the same place as left_top div.

It goes for all the rows - the mid_top/mid_mid/mid_bot divs are positioned exactly in the same spot as left_top/left_mid/left_bot divs(as I said only in browser debug view, in design view it looks all good).

Here is my painting of the problem to make it easier to understand:

[image: Painting of the problem]

Here is the code:

ASPX:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="page">
            <div id="left_side"></div>
            <div id="right_side">
                <div id="row1">
                    <div id="left_top"></div>
                    <div id="right_top"></div>
                     <div id="mid_top"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="row2">
                    <div id="left_mid"></div>
                    <div id="right_mid"></div>
                    <div id="mid_mid"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="row3">
                    <div id="left_bot"></div>
                    <div id="right_bot"></div>
                    <div id="mid_bot"></div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS stylesheet:

```css
body {
    height:800px;
    width:1200px;
}

#form1{
    height:800px;
    width:1200px;
}

#page{
    height:800px;
    width:1200px;
}

#left_side{
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}

#right_side{
    height:100%;
    width:75%;
    float:right;
}

#row1{
    height:33%;
    width:100%;
}

#left_top{
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
      float:left;
}

#right_top{
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    float:right;

}

#mid_top{
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    border:dashed;
    border-width:1px;
}

#row2{
    height:33%;
    width:100%;
}

#left_mid{
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    border:dashed;
    border-width:1px;

}

#right_mid{
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    float:right;
    border:dashed;
    border-width:1px;

}

#mid_mid{
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
}

#row3{
    height:33%;
    width:100%;
}

#left_bot{
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}

#right_bot{
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    float:right;
}

#mid_bot{
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    border:dashed;
    border-width:1px;

}
```

Left_side DIV is unnecessary here - I will use it later for the project. All the action is in right_side DIV.

As you can see I tried adding some meta header but I don't exactly know what is it doing and it didn't change anything anyway.

I also tried to play with setting things like display:block, display:inline, display:inline-block etc, but to no avail... I don't know why isn't it working when it worked just fine before.

Comment: How about keeping your language at a mature level? I edited out your unnecessary vulgarity - no place for that here. And no place to be begging for help or discussing your stress level (I removed all of that as well). Just... ask your question.

Comment: use bootstrap css framework. your layout will never change if you show in mobile device as will. learn bootstrap from below link. and don't suicide please you are my bro!
http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Cheers bro! However, we can't use javascript in our codes, so I can't really use that. Anyway clearly the suicide part was an over-exaggeration, I didn't want to offend anyone with my language either - I'm used to the way people post at reddit and such sites where it's a norm, suppose I should have adjusted my post to more formal level that belongs here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, a working example of what you're trying to do - I changed the HTML and CSS a bit, so if you're bound by using the floats and such, then it won't work, but elsewise it does exactly what you want.

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0; padding; 0;
  }
body {
    height:800px;
    width:1200px;
}

#form1{
    height:800px;
    width:1200px;
}

#page{
    height:800px;
    width:1200px;
}

#left_side{
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
  display: none;
}

#right_side{
    height:100%;
    width:75%;
    float:right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#row1 div,#row2 div, #row3 div {
  display: inline-block;
  }
.row .left,.row .right {
  width: 25%;
  }
.row .middle {
  width: 50%;
  }
#left_top{
  border: 1px solid blue;  
}
#right_top{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#mid_top{
    border: 1px dashed brown;
}
#left_mid{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#right_mid{
   border: 1px solid green;
}
#left_bot{
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
#right_bot{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#mid_bot{
  border: 1px dashed brown;  
}
#row1,#row2,#row3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 33%;
  width: 100%;
  }
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
div div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="page">
            <div id="left_side"></div>
            <div id="right_side">
                <div id="row1" class="row">
                    <div id="left_top" class="left"></div><div id="mid_top" class="middle"></div><div id="right_top" class="right"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="row2" class="row">
                    <div id="left_mid" class="left"></div><div id="mid_mid" class="middle"></div><div id="right_mid" class="right"></div>                  
                </div>
                <div id="row3" class="row">
                    <div id="left_bot" class="left"></div><div id="mid_bot" class="middle"></div><div id="right_bot" class="right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick! We are not bound to use floats, only that our lecturer suggested that it might be a good idea, and while it worked at uni PCs, it does not work anywhere else. Don't know what would be the reason for that! Either way - your code seems to do the trick just fine, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is something more along the lines of what you're looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/hzk2yxpv

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.middle {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

If you're going to be using floats, I would recommend looking into [float clearing](https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/) so you don't run into problems in the future, or if you're feeling really adventurous, [flex boxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Also, always remember that the height of the element is always going to be relative to the parent container. If you have `height: auto` on an element and any parent up the chain of parent's height isn't specified, then the height will appear as zero.

Comment: Thanks! The height seems to be equal as zero in this example when I debug this in IE, however works just fine in chrome. I'm still a complete beginner, but I noticed that it's often the case that the code will work just fine in one browser, and wrong in another. 
Sadly though, our lecturer debugs in IE so it got to work there aswell.
However, the answer brought by junkfoodjunkie seems to do the trick in both cases!

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you without float. Using flex-box is more straight forward. I hope you find it easy to follow. I have not changed your code much so that you can see.

```css
/*an example of doing it with flexbox, I have not changed your syntax too much, so that you can figure out how it works */

body {
  height: 800px;
  width: 1200px;
}
#form1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*let the rows flex in column */
  height: 800px;
  width: 1200px;
}
#page {
  height: 800px;
  width: 1200px;
}
#row1,
#row2,
#row3 {
  display: flex;
  height: 33%;
  width: 100%;
}
#left_top,
#right_top {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /*specifies how much the item will grow relative to the rest of the flexible items inside the same container. */
  height: 100%;
}
#mid_top,
#left_mid,
#mid_bot,
#right_mid {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  border: dashed;
  border-width: 1px;
}
#mid_mid,
#left_bot,
#right_bot {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="page">
      <div id="row1">
        <div id="left_top">left-top</div>
        <div id="mid_top">mid-top</div>
        <div id="right_top">right-top</div>
      </div>
      <div id="row2">
        <div id="left_mid">left-mid</div>
        <div id="mid_mid">mid-mid</div>
        <div id="right_mid">right-mid</div>
      </div>
      <div id="row3">
        <div id="left_bot">left-bot</div>
        <div id="mid_bot">mid-bot</div>
        <div id="right_bot">right-bot</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Surprisingly - this is working in Chrome only, when I debug in IE the boxes are positioned in one column one under another!

Comment: Glad it worked. Css3 is implemented in the newer browsers as IE11 and up.

Comment: Glad it worked. Css3 is implemented in the newer browsers as IE11 and up. Try adding prefix -ms- before flex. Ex. "-ms-flex-direction" and "-ms-flex"